# Issue with Custom Post Types and Permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have created 2 x Wordpress Custom Post Types

One is called Category, the other is Products and the products have the categories as the parent with the code below:

Products

```
function my_custom_post_product() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Products', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Product' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Products' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Product' ),
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Products' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No products found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No products found in the Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Products'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'description'   => 'Holds our products and product specific data',
    'public'        => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','page-attributes' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => '',
        'with_front' => false,
    )


);
register_post_type( 'product', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_product' );
```

Categories

```
function my_custom_post_category() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => _x( 'Categories', 'post type general name' ),
    'singular_name'      => _x( 'Category', 'post type singular name' ),
    'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'book' ),
    'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Category' ),
    'new_item'           => __( 'New Category' ),
    'all_items'          => __( 'All Categories' ),
    'view_item'          => __( 'View Category' ),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'search_items'       => __( 'Search Categories' ),
    'not_found'          => __( 'No categories found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No categories found in the Trash' ),
    'parent_item_colon'  => '',
    'menu_name'          => 'Categories'
);
$args = array(
    'labels'        => $labels,
    'description'   => 'Category Pages',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public'        => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','post-formats','custom-fields','page-attributes' ),
    'has_archive'   => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'query_var' => 'category',

);
register_post_type( 'category', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_category' );
```

The issue I am having is with the permalinks, at the minute they are like this:

Category - http://domain.com/category/category-name/
Product - http://domain.com/product/category-name/product-name/

I would want to make it like this:

Category - http://domain.com/category-name/
Product - http://domain.com/category-name/product-name/

I have tried various things but it just ends up giving a 404 even after refreshing permalink settings.

Comment: This question has been asked here many times, if you search around you will find possible solutions.

Comment: I have tried a few things from other articles, the usual answer is to change the permalink options in the array and then just click save on the permalink options but I cant seem to find anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using category as cpt try rename it for example in product-type. For more information on category see on codex: [Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)

```
function my_custom_post_product_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Product Types' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Product Type' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Product Type' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Product Type' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Product Type' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Product Types' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Product Type' ),
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Product Types' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Product Types found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Product Types found in the Trash' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Product Types'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => 'Product Type Pages',
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'menu_position'      => 5,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','post-formats','custom-fields','page-attributes' ),
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'can_export'         => true,
        'query_var'          => 'product-type'
    );

    register_post_type( 'product-type', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_product_type' );
```